# Oracle - drop multiple table in a single query

Tags: oracle, ddl

I have fifty tables in a database, in that I need only six tables.

How can I delete remaining tables by one single query?

Comment: If I were you, I will export the six tables, drop everything, and restore the six tables.

Comment: Don't you have any tool like SQL Developer or Toad? Simply click the tables (using shift and ctrl if you like), then click Drop.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have sql developer but problem is that I can select multiple tables but after selecting multiple tables it is not giving "Drop" option.

Comment: Oh, too bad. Sorry I didn't know that. I thought all those tools would offer that simple functionality. I'm using Toad.

Comment: the best solution is given by @Raptor: easy and fast and secure ...

Comment: How do you drop all tables in Oracle SQL Developer though? Or do you just run a script?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can generate a list of DROP TABLE commands with the query below:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name || ';' FROM user_tables;
```

After that you remove your six tables you want to keep and execute the other commands. Or you add a `WHERE table_name NOT IN (...)` clause to the query.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it is giving error when I run.SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.  I used this query  SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name || ';' FROM pmd_dba; here pmd_dba is database

Comment: No, you have to use `user_tables`. It's a view of all tables where you are the owner.

Answer (score 18):

Use something like this, as there is no direct command or way in oracle to do this

```
begin
  for rec in (select table_name 
              from   all_tables 
              where  table_name like '%ABC_%'
             )
  loop
    execute immediate 'drop table '||rec.table_name;
  end loop;             
end;
/
```

Comment: I'd also add CASCADE CONSTRAINTS

Comment: And I would use `user_tables` instead of `all_tables`. Otherwise it's possible to drop a table with the same name in an other schema (If you have DROP permissions).

Comment: @Deepu in where clause we can use "not in" operator and then we put all six names over there?

Comment: @myself: Ok, it's not possible, because in the `DROP TABLE` command is no schema name. In worst case, it will result in an error, because the table is already dropped, but that is not so tragic :)

Comment: @vim yes it should be possible

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the answer, 
for Oracle 10 versions and later, dropped tables are not deleted permanently, but moved to recycled bin. To truly delete tables need to add optional parameter PURGE.

Expanding on the accepted answer :

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name || ' PURGE ;' DB_DEATH FROM user_tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

First Run this query with table names that you want to keep.

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'mydatabase' AND table_name not in ('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
```

This query will give you DROP table query.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select from the list on the left all the tables you want to drop. Drag and drop them in your worksheet. Select Object Name from the pop-up window
2. Press the Edit menu and select Replace.
3. Type in the find field the comma symbol `,`
4. Type in the replace field the following text `;\ndrop table` . Note that there is a space after the word table. Replace all.
5. Type `drop table`  before your first table and `;` after your last one.
6. You are ready to drop your tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 
  TYPE bulk_array is table of ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%type; 
  array bulk_array;
BEGIN

 SELECT OWNER ||'.'|| TABLE_NAME BULK COLLECT 
   INTO array
   FROM ALL_TABLES 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%%';--HERE U WILL PUT YOUR CONDITIONS.


    FOR i IN array.FIRST..array.LAST LOOP
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '|| array(i) || ' PURGE'; --Specify PURGE if you want to drop the table and release the space associated
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables you want to keep are `keep_tab1`, `keep_tab2`, etc. or start with ASB..   
use `regexp_like`. Here just to show an example with `regexp_like`  
The loop continues even when an error occurs dropping one of the tables.You may
have to run this script multiple times as errors may occur when dropping a primary table without having dropped the referential tables first.

```
begin 
for rec in (
           select table_name  from   user_tables 
           where  not   
           regexp_like(table_name, 'keep_tab1|keep_tab2|^ASB')  
           ) 
loop  
    begin  
    execute immediate 'drop table '||rec.table_name;  
    exception when others then   
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.table_name||':'||sqlerrm);  
    end;  
end loop;               
end;
```